# How to modify a property of a CMIS document using DotCMIS/OpenCMIS

Tags: cmis, opencmis, dotcmis

Let's say I have a document `doc` and I want to update its `barcode` metadata to `"01234"`.

The document might have existing other properties, I don't want to lose them.
In case `doc` already has a `barcode`, it will be overwritten.

How to do this with DotCMIS/OpenCMIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CMIS, updating properties will overwrite existing values by default, and properties you don't send along with the updateProperties message are by default retained. That is to say that both your requirements are already guaranteed by the protocol semantic.

Code wise, have a look at the `Updating properties` [code sample](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-update.html) for OpenCMIS, here's it applied to your case:

```
CmisObject cmisobject = ....
Map<String, Object> updateProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updateProperties.put("acme:barcode", "new value"); // single-value property
cmisobject.updateProperties(updateProperties);
```

In case of DotCMIS, the [samples page](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/getting-started-with-dotcmis.html) offer another useful snippet, here's the modified version to map your use case:

```
ICmisObject cmisObject = ...

IDictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
properties["acme:barcode"] = "new value";
IObjectId newId = cmisObject.UpdateProperties(properties);

if (newId.Id == cmisObject.Id) 
{
    // the repository updated this object - refresh the object
    cmisObject.Refresh();
}
else
{
    // the repository created a new version - fetch the new version
    cmisObject = session.GetObject(newId);
}
```

Comment: "properties you don't send along with the updateProperties message are by default retained" ← Thanks, I did not know that! I was worried that I would need to fill the `new Dictionary<string, object>()` with all properties I needed.

Comment: when in doubt, it's always worth to check out the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/os/cmis-spec-v1.0.html)