# Does CMIS allow writeonly properties?

Tags: cmis

I want to fill the specified property on create a document. Server will have to calculate another properties and forget about original value.
Have read 1.1 (latest) specification, but didn't find any mentions about the issue.

Comment: Did not understand your question properly...can you please elaborate ?

Comment: For example, I want to add documents by URL. User (Chemistry Workbench client) opens document add dialog, input link and server will download the document from URL. But there are no reasons to keep original URL for document in properties.

Comment: still not clear..probably little bit code can also help...but you can obviously update the value of some of your properties...check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142353/how-to-modify-a-property-of-a-cmis-document-using-dotcmis-opencmis

Comment: @saurav no. I meant property that depended on another property.